# writing proper xml missing values white node

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I have progressed to writing my settings out in nodes for example.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Propertise");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

XmlNode userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Property");
XmlAttribute attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("default");
attribute.Value = "4.5";
userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("amount");
attribute.Value = "4.5";
userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
attribute.Value = "some setting name";
userNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);
```

but this is missing an end property tag in the XML.

What part do I have to change to complete the missing  tag?

Comment: I would suggest moving `xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);` to after `rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not missing end property tag. It is self-closing tag, because it doesn't have any child nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Propertise>
  <Property default="4.5" amount="4.5" name="some setting name" />
                                                                ^
                                                                |
                                                             It is closed here.
</Propertise>
```

Once you add some child nodes inside it will have closing tag in another line, like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Propertise>
  <Property default="4.5" amount="4.5" name="some setting name">
    <OtherProperty />
  </Property>
</Propertise>
```

You might also want to use XDocument instead of XmlDocument next time, as I think it makes creating xml documents much simpler:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
 new XElement("Properties",
 new XElement("Property",
     new XAttribute("default", "4.5"),
     new XAttribute("amount", "4.5"),
     new XAttribute("name", "some setting name"))));
```